# from resize event

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, tabpage

[image]

l want to know from resize event. 
tabpage1 content contains one circle button. l don't know the circle button auto resize.

```
namespace UITest
{
  public partial class Form2 : Form
  {
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void pictureBox2_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox2.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - pictureBox2.Width) / 13;
        pictureBox2.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - pictureBox2.Height) / 13;
    }
  }
}
```

l apply this code. but didn't work. what should I do?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Have you set the anchors of the button?

Comment: if i increase the screen form, l want that button location is auto size like screen ratio,

Answer (score 2):

You need to set anchors for your button. In your case, I suppose you need this combination.
[image: Anchor image]

Anchors simply set a control's position to be relative with the form edges. To do this navigate to your form designer, *right click that button* -> *properties*. Find anchor in the properties designer box and click arrow down button. Then you can select/deselect anchors by clicking on them.

Comment: This will not change the size but only fix the right-bottom distance.

Comment: And that's what OP asked for. Wording is broken in q, but I am pretty sure this is the intended behaviour.

Comment: He mentions auto-resize twice.

Comment: the anchored object will only be resized is you anchor it to opposite sides, so in this case to all four.